# .NET library to generate a video file from bitmap sequence

Tags: .net, video

Is there any .NET libraries to generate video files (any type) from a given sequence of bitmap images?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

*http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx*

It is written in C# and it can create a avi video stream from a list of bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks Presidenten, I had to put that project on hold but I'll definetely have a look at your link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Splicer](http://www.codeplex.com/splicer) to do this.

Please see example 3 at http://www.codeplex.com/splicer/Wiki/View.aspx?title=News%20Feeds&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Thanks Anders, I had to put that project on hold but I'll definetely have a look at your link.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a bit late to this thread but I [Bitmap to video](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/220-bitmaps-into-videos.html) uses old vfw technology to do the job in C#